# How do I use commands to fill my floor for a parkour map?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I have tried many things as well as looking things up, including some suggestions from this site. I need to know how to use the command `fill` for Minecraft Education Edition 1.12.5.

Comment: What many things have you tried? First hit on google brings me to [this page](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/fill_command.php), which (seemingly) answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Copied verbatim from the [DigMinecraft website](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/fill_command.php) (first hit searching for "*Minecraft Education Edition fill command*"):

> **Fill Command in Minecraft Education Edition**
>
> In Minecraft Education Edition, there are 2 syntaxes for the `/fill` command.
>
> To fill a region with a type of block:
>
> `/fill <from> <to> <tileName> [tileData] [outline¦hollow¦destroy¦keep]`
>
> To replace one type of block in a region with another type of block:
>
> `/fill <from> <to> <tileName> [tileData] replace <replaceTileName> <replaceDataValue>`
>
> **Definitions**
>
> - `<from>` is the starting x y z coordinate for the fill region (i.e. first corner block).
> - `<to>` is the ending x y z coordinate for the fill region (i.e. opposite corner block).
> - `<tileName>` is name of the block to fill the region.
> - `<tileData>` is optional. It is the data type or variation of the block if more than one type exists for that `tileName`.
> - `<replace>` will replace all blocks in the fill region, including air.
> - `<outline>` is optional. It will replace blocks on the outer edge of the fill region, but does not replace the inner blocks.
> - `<hollow>` is optional. It will replace blocks on the outer edge of the fill region, and replaces inner blocks with air.
> - `<keep>` is optional. It will replace only air blocks in the fill region.
> - `<destroy>` is optional. It will replace all blocks in the fill region, including air.
>     Replaced blocks will be dropped and can then be collected as if they were mined with a pickaxe or shovel.
> - `<replaceTileName>` is the name of the block that will be replaced.
> - `<replaceDataValue>` is the variation of the block to be replaced if more than one type exists for that `replaceTileName`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more simplified answer

/fill *x* *y* *Z* *x* *y* *z* |what you want to fill|

Comment: We prefer detailed answers over simple ones. You should only post a new answer if you have additional information to add that hasn't already been said.